# Unable to format external SSD drive which was member of a raid

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I try to reuse this drive as a single storage but if I zero it's super blocks then it restarts the md127 component.
Tried everything like format from windows 7 with no avail...

Comment: How exactly did you zero its superblocks? (In any case you have to do that with array *stopped*.)

Comment: With mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdb1, and before that mdadm --stop /dev/md127

Comment: Have you tried using a linux cd and either the `dd` command to nuke the boot partition, or gparted to reformat it?